# Importing Mongoose Models into main app as Git Submodule

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on an Express API project and have come across an issue. I want to import my Mongoose models into the main project as a Git submodule. The idea is to keep my models in a separate repository for modularity across a few APIs. However, I'm running into issues ensuring that the mongoose connection established in my app.ts is being correctly utilized by the models in the submodule.

Has anyone here had experience with setting up Mongoose models as a Git submodule for an Express project? How did you manage to ensure that the submodule models use the same mongoose connection as the main app? Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated!

In my main app, I ensure that the Mongoose connection is opened before importing any models or handling any routes. After the connection is established, I import the models from the submodule into my route handlers. I’ve added logs around the database connection process and within the model usage in routes to confirm that the connection is successful and models are loaded. Also the paths used to import the submodule models are correct.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.